# Using only for loop and if statement (no built in functions), group the similar values in a column and add the corresponding values in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement

I have a following dataframe - df (this is a demo one, actual one is very big):

| Text | Score |
| --- | --- |
| 'I love pizza!' | 2 |
| 'I love pizza!' | 1 |
| 'I love pizza!' | 3 |
| 'Python rules!' | 0 |
| 'Python rules!' | 5 |

I want to group the 'Text' column values and then add the following rows of the 'Score' column.
The output I desire is thus:

| Text | Score | Sum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 'I love pizza!' | 2 | 6 |
| 'I love pizza!' | 1 | 6 |
| 'I love pizza!' | 3 | 6 |
| 'Python rules!' | 0 | 5 |
| 'Python rules!' | 5 | 5 |

I know how to get the desired output using Python/Pandas groupby and sum() (and aggregate) methods, for instance,

```
df1 = df.groupby('Text')['Score'].sum().reset_index(name='Sum')
df3 = df.merge(df1, on='Text', how='left')
```

However, I do not want to use any such in-built functions. I want to only use simple for loop and if statement to accomplish this.

I tried doing this the following way:

```
def func(df):
    # NOTE, CANNOT USE LIST APPEND (as it is an in-built function).
    sum = 0
    n = len(df['text']) # NEED TO WORK FOR-LOOP USING INTEGERS AND HENCE NEED LENGTH
   
    for i in range(0,n):
        exists = False  #flag to track repeated values

        for j in range(i+1,n):            
            if df['text'][i] == df['text'][j]: # IF TRUE, THEN THE 'TEXT' ROWS ARE SIMILAR I.E. GROUPED
                exists = True
                sum = df['score'][i] + df['score'][j]
                
                break;  
        
        if not exists:
            sum += sum

    return sum

df['Sum'] = func(df)
```

The output for this script is incorrect:

| Text | Score | Sum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 'I love pizza!' | 2 | 10 |
| 'I love pizza!' | 1 | 10 |
| 'I love pizza!' | 3 | 10 |
| 'Python rules!' | 0 | 10 |
| 'Python rules!' | 5 | 10 |

I have tried playing around with the above script, I get different results, but never the correct one. Any help with this is greatly appreciated!
Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: `listname.append(value)` can be replaced with `listname += [value]`

Comment: Why do you need to use loops? Is this for an assignment?

Comment: Why even bother using pandas if you're not using its methods? You might as well use lists and dictionaries.

Comment: The reason why I need to use loops is that I need to make this calculation/work in C. As in C, one needs many more lines and frequent compilations to view the output, I usually try to perform the work first in Python using similar C logic and then, once it works in python, I can then simply export it to C with proper additions of C syntex.

Comment: Your C code is going to need some way to add to the array that replaces the list. So write the Python code using `append()`, then convert that to the corresponding C code. The overall logic is the same, but Python lists and C arrays are different enough that you can't write the detailed code in the same way.

Comment: Hello Barmar, first, thank you for all your feedback! I am using Cython. When passing the arguments to the function, I convert the dataframe column into numpy array and then in the C function, convert that array to a C array. Hence, I thought to write the above function as I did. I am still quite naive when it comes to both C and python, so I hope I am clear enough with my explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Herein is the script that produces the correct output for the above question:

```
def func(df):
    result = []
    final_result = []
    n = len(df['Text'])
    #Add a list of zeros the same length as the original list (= n) to flag positions already checked
    flags = [0] * n
    for k in range(0,n):
        sum = df['Score'][k]
        for i in range(0,n):
            #Step to skip (continue) without doing anything if the position has already been flagged (processed, counted)
            if flags[i]:
                continue
            else:
                if i==k:
                    for j in range(i+1,n):
                        if df['Text'][i]==df['Text'][j]: #If true, then the 'Text' rows are similar, i.e. grouped
                            #Every time there is a match, the position is flageed by turning it to 1
                            flags[j] = 1
                            sum += df['Score'][j]                    
                    result = sum                    
                    break        
        final_result += [result]
        
    return final_result


df['Sum'] = func(df)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).